# Multiplying Matrix and Vector in MPI C

Tags: c, matrix, vector, mpi

I have a task for my current MPI Class where I have to multiply the 2x3 Matrix

1 2 3

4 5 6

by the 3x1 vector
7 8 9

I am told to assume we only have 2 processors.

I have the following implmenetation but I am going into deadlock and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(void)
{
    int comm_sz; /* number of processes*/
    int my_rank; /* my process rank */
    int m, n;
    double* Matrix;
    double* Vector;
    double* Result;
    double* localMatrix;

    MPI_Comm comm;


    FILE *fptr = fopen("mv-data.txt", "r");
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &comm_sz);
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &my_rank);

    if (my_rank == 0)
    {
        fscanf(fptr,"%d", m);
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", n);
    }
    MPI_Bcast(m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);
    MPI_Bcast(n,1,MPI_INT, 0, comm);


    if (my_rank==0)
    {
    Matrix = malloc(m*n * sizeof(double));

    for(int i = 0; i<m; i++)
        for(int j=0; j< n; j++)
            fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &Matrix[i*n+j]);

    Vector = malloc(n*sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        fscanf(fptr,"%lf", &Vector[i]);


    Result = malloc(m * sizeof(double));



    for (int row = 0; row < m; row++)
    {
        localMatrix = malloc(m*sizeof(double));
        for(int column = 0; column < n; column++)
            localMatrix[column] = Matrix[row*n + column];

        MPI_Send(localMatrix, n, MPI_DOUBLE, row % comm_sz, 0, comm);
    }

    }
    MPI_Bcast(Vector, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,comm);
    MPI_Recv(localMatrix, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    Result[my_rank] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Result[my_rank] += localMatrix[i] * Vector[i];
    }

    if (my_rank = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            printf("%d", Result[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I can't think of any other way to send this process to the master processor without causing deadlock.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use collective operations: scatter the matrix, broadcast the vector and gather the result. `if(tank == 0)` will only remain at the very beginning and at the very end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In `rank 0`, you are using a blocking `MPI_Send`. Other processes are then calling a collective `MPI_Bcast` instead of a matching `MPI_Recv`. This **may** cause a **deadlock** (Buffering can happen inside `MPI_Send` and may also avoid deadlock). See below:

```
if (my_rank==0)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < m; row++)
   {
      MPI_Send(localMatrix, n, MPI_DOUBLE, row % comm_sz, 0, comm);
   }
}
MPI_Bcast(Vector, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,comm); // COLLECTIVE - PROCESS MAY GET STUCK HERE
MPI_Recv(localMatrix, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

You can try something like this,

```
if (my_rank==0)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < m; row++)
   {
      MPI_Send(localMatrix, n, MPI_DOUBLE, row % comm_sz, 0, comm);
   }
} else
{
      MPI_Recv(localMatrix, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
MPI_Bcast(Vector, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0,comm);
```

which will definitely avoid deadlock. Also, there are issues in your code. For example,

```
MPI_Recv(localMatrix, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

will cause a segmentation fault because memory for `localMatrix` is not allocated. Accessing `Result` as well as `Vector` also causes segmentation fault because you have not allocated memory for it in **other processes (eg: ranks 1 to N-1)** except **rank 0**.